# What's the name of this small, round, light green squash?

Tags: identification, squash

This is a small, round, slightly flattened, light green squash. The average size is a bit bigger than a round plum (cirruela in Spanish).

It looks quite distinct from Round zucchini but it might be just a variety of the same group ([Cucurbita pepo summer pumpkin group](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Cucurbita_pepo_summer_pumpkin_group))

The only similar variety that I could find is this [Ronde de Nice (AKA Gourmet Globe)](https://modernfarmer.com/2015/08/summer-squash-varieties/) but when googling it, I can only find images with Round zucchini.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would you be willing to break a few open and post a picture so we can see what the inside looks like? Also, are these guys soft or hard? Have you tasted one? If so, can you describe the taste? Editing the information right into your question is more helpful than answering in comments, so if you could do that, it would be great! Thanks!

Comment: They are sold by the fruit shop owners from Pakistan, I asked them and they told me it's [Tinda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinda). I'll add photos on Wikimedia Commons soon.

Comment: .. And now I need to know how to plural this word. "Tindas" is ok?

Comment: How many seeds does each fruit have? Is it just one like Chayote? (I'm not saying it is Chayote, as it looks different, but the answer could be helpful in identification.) Or are there multiple as with Zucchini and similar.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hellow, I'm rahma.. I don't know if they are the same, in swahili  we call it gogonti in plural are magogonti, these fruits are very intense you can't eat without salt and I Don't know the effects but I really like them.